# Why does an up-to-date ClickOnce application perform upgrade?

Tags: clickonce

We have a ClickOnce application configured to automatically upgrade.  On a few of the client machines, the application is running for days, and then mysteriously "upgrades" before launching.  This upgrade is unexpected as the user was already running the most up to date version, and we did not publish a new version.

One suspicious clue is that there were more than 2 folders in the ClickOnce installation cache (C:\Documents and Settings\\Local Settings\Apps\2.0).  Instead of 2 folders (one named "Data" and the other with a mangled name), there are 6 folders (one "Data" and several with mangled names).

Has anyone else ran into this issue of unexpected upgrades?

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Is the application actually updating?  Maybe you are just seeing the flash of the progress bar as it's checking for updates.

Run [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to see exactly what files are being downloaded when this update happens.

Comment: Hi - thank you for the reply.  Yes, the application is actually updating (and not just the "Verifying Application") and the file timestamps in the ClickOnce cache confirm that.  Fiddler would be a nice option, but unfortunately, I haven't been able to reproduce the problem.  This happens on the customer machine only.

Comment: Have you seen it first-hand?  If not, I suggest you do, users can be sure of something whereas they may be misinterpreting.  If you do have direct access, you could then use Fiddler.  If they have restrictive IT rules, see if you can get their IT dept. involved.